# Java error (No active SparkContext) when attempting to create SparkSession in pyspark 3.4.1 over spark server of version 3.3.2

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, multiple-versions

got this failure when trying to connect to an active spark server

```
Failure in Test: Py4JJavaError('An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.', JavaObject id=o141)
...
return SparkSession.builder.master(spark_address). 
  */pyspark/sql/session.py:480 ......................................... getOrCreate >> session = SparkSession(sc, options=self._options)
  */pyspark/sql/session.py:525 ............................................ __init__ >> jsparkSession = self._jvm.SparkSession(self._jsc.sc(), options)
  */py4j/java_gateway.py:1587 ............................................. __call__ >> return_value = get_return_value(
  */py4j/protocol.py:326 .......................................... get_return_value >> raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.
: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext.
This stopped SparkContext was created at:

org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

The currently active SparkContext was created at:

(No active SparkContext.)

    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.assertNotStopped(SparkContext.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.<init>(SparkSession.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.<init>(SparkSession.scala:107)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
E: <Error: py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.
: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext.
This stopped SparkContext was created at:

org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

The currently active SparkContext was created at:

(No active SparkContext.)

    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.assertNotStopped(SparkContext.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.<init>(SparkSession.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.<init>(SparkSession.scala:107)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)>
```

i've started a Spark server using version 3.3.2, but my pyspark is of a newer version (3.4.1)
when i create a SparkSession object i get the following error:

is this a known issue? (is it by design due to version mismatch?)
is there a work-around?

note - when i change pyspark version to 3.3.2 the connection is successful